# How does a block device driver handle IO errors

Tags: drivers, io, block-device, scsi

When a block device gets a request to read a range of sectors, and one of those sectors has a read failure, how does the driver signal to the kernel that a *partial* read is available, and that the specific sector *number x* failed?

I've skimmed the chapter in Linux Device Drivers on block devices, but didn't see it discussed.

[On a deeper level, how does the SCSI protocol implement such communication?]